# zf3 getServiceManager in constructor of controller

Tags: zend-framework3

How I can call method getServiceManager in constructor of controller?

If I in action method it's ok

```
  public function __construct()
    {

      $this->logger =  $this->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get("Zend\Log\Logger\Debug");

    }
```

, but in constructor  getServiceManager  give error:

```
Call to a member function getServiceManager() on null in C:\htdocs\test-zend2\module\Application\src\Controller\IndexController.php on line 32.
```

Comment: You should inject dependencies in the constructor, so if you need whole ServiceManager you should inject it (that is not recommended)...

Comment: I see this in article, but after zend1 i don't understand why it's so hard? Thanks

Comment: Yap that's true :/  Basically this is the answer and mini tutorial how to do it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168619/servicemanager-in-zf3/42176170#42176170

Comment: Thanks  tasmaniski)), work,  but why )) thanks!

Comment: The serviceManager use to be accessible from the controller in ZF2 but it has been deprecated and remove a while ago. This is anti-pattern right now, and you should seek for alternatives instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServiceManager in ZF3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168619/servicemanager-in-zf3)

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider posting an answer to your questions and accepting it yourself or deleting the question.