# Zend 3 - using logger as service

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zend-log

I am quite novice with ZF3 and I can't figure out how should I define a logger module as a service and how could I use (reuse) it in other modules. The official [documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-log/service-manager/) is poor from this point of view. Any short example would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use zend-log in ZF app, after installation you need to do 2 thing:

1. To register `Zend\Log` in the application config under the 'modules' key.
2. Add config for your logger in global.php or module config

   ```
   'log' => [
     'MyLogger' => [
       'writers' => [
           'stream' => [
               'name' => 'stream',
               'priority' => \Zend\Log\Logger::ALERT,
               'options' => [
                   'stream' => '/tmp/php_errors.log',
                   'formatter' => [
                       'name' => \Zend\Log\Formatter\Simple::class,
                       'options' => [
                           'format' => '%timestamp% %priorityName% (%priority%): %message% %extra%',
                           'dateTimeFormat' => 'c',
                       ],
                   ],
                   'filters' => [
                       'priority' => [
                           'name' => 'priority',
                           'options' => [
                               'operator' => '<=',
                               'priority' => \Zend\Log\Logger::INFO,
                           ],
                       ],
                   ],
               ],
           ],
       ],
     ],
   ],
   ```

after that just take it from Service Manager and use it:

```
$logger = $container->get('MyLogger'); // <-- the key that you register in config above
$logger->info('Logging info message in the file');
```

You probably want to take logger from SM and than inject it in a class that you want to use it.

There is a god blog post about Logging with [zend-log](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-09-12-zend-log.html)

Comment: And from where comes that `$container` variable?

Comment: $container is in the FACTORY class of your original class, please see my other answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/42176170/949273